# How can I fix these errors? "redefinition of 'template std::ostream& operator<<" , "unresolved overloaded function type"

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following code:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H_
#define MATRIX_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::ostream;
using std::vector;
using std::string;


class BadDims: public std::exception {
public:
    const char* what() const throw () override {
        return "Bad dimensions";
    }
};

template<class T>
class Row {
    std::vector<T> row;
public:
    Row() = default;
    Row(int cols) :
            row(cols, T()) {
    }
    ~Row() = default;
    Row& operator=(const Row& r) = default;
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const {
        if (i < 0 || i >= row.size()) {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        return this->row[i];
    }

    T& operator[](unsigned int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= row.size()) {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        return this->row[i];
    }
};

template<class T>
T Plus(const T& t1, const T& t2) {
    return t1 + t2;
}

template<class T>
class Matrix {
    Row<T>* rows;
    int numberOfRows; // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ error1
    int numberOfCols; // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ error2

public:
    Matrix(int numberOfRows, int numberOfCols) :
            rows(new Row<T> [numberOfRows]), numberOfRows(
                    numberOfRows), numberOfCols(numberOfCols) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
            this->rows[i] = Row<T>(numberOfCols);
        }
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        delete[] rows;
    }

    Matrix(const Matrix& m) :
            rows(new Row<T> [m.numberOfRows]), numberOfRows(m.numberOfRows), numberOfCols(m.numberOfCols) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.numberOfRows; i++) {
            this->rows[i] = m.rows[i];
        }
    }

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix<T>& m) {
        if (this == &m) {
            return *this;
        }
        if (this->numberOfCols != m.numberOfCols
                || this->numberOfRows != m.numberOfRows) {
            throw BadDims();
        }
        Row<T>* newRows = new Row<T> [m.numberOfRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.numberOfRows; i++) {
            newRows[i] = m.rows[i];
        }
        delete[] this->rows;
        this->rows = newRows;
        return *this;
    }

    const Row<T>& operator[](int i) const {
        if (i < 0 || i >= this->numberOfRows) {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        return this->rows[i];
    }

    Row<T>& operator[](int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= this->numberOfRows) {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        return this->rows[i];
    }

    void getDimensions(int* outN, int* outM) const {
        if (outN == NULL || outM == NULL) {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        *outN = numberOfRows;
        *outM = numberOfCols;
    }

    template<class S>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix<S>& m) { // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ error3
        for (int i = 0; i < m.numberOfRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.numberOfCols; j++) {
                os << m[i][j] << " ";
            }
            os << std::endl;
        }
        return os;
    }

    Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix<T>& m) {
        if (this->numberOfCols != m.numberOfCols
                || this->numberOfRows != m.numberOfRows) {
            throw BadDims();
        }
        *this = *(matAction(this, &m, Plus)); // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ error4
        return *this;
    }
};

template<class T, class Action>
Matrix<T>* matAction(const Matrix<T>* m1, const Matrix<T>* m2, Action action) {
    if (m1 == NULL || m2 == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int rows1 = 0, cols1 = 0;
    m1->getDimensions(&rows1, &cols1);
    int rows2 = 0, cols2 = 0;
    m2->getDimensions(&rows2, &cols2);
    if (rows1 != rows2 || cols1 != cols2) {
        throw std::exception();
    }
    Matrix<T>* res = new Matrix<T>(rows1, cols1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols1; j++) {
            (*res)[i][j] = action((*m1)[i][j], (*m2)[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& m1, const Matrix<T>& m2) {
    return Matrix<T>(m1) += m2;
}

/*
 * Implementation of Vector by Matrix.
 */
template<class T>
class Vector: public Matrix<T> {
public:
    Vector(int cols) :
            Matrix<T>(1, cols) {
    }

    const T operator[](int col) const {
        return Matrix<T>::operator[](0).operator[](col);
    }

    T& operator[](int col) {
        return Matrix<T>::operator[](0).operator[](col);
    }
};

/*
 * SquareMatrix from size SIZE x SIZE.
 */
template<class T, int SIZE>
class SquareMatrix: public Matrix<T> {
public:
    SquareMatrix() :
            Matrix<T>(SIZE, SIZE) {
    }
    template<class S, int N>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const SquareMatrix<S, N>& m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.numberOfRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.numberOfCols; j++) {
                os << m[i][j] << " ";
            }
            os << std::endl;
        }
        return os;
    }
};

#endif /* MATRIX_H_ */
```

I get the following errors (four errors, you can find them by `ctrl+f` with search the word `error`):

> 'int Matrix::numberOfRows' is private
>
> 'int Matrix::numberOfCols' is private
>
> redefinition of 'template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix&)'
>
> no matching function for call to 'matAction(Matrix*, const Matrix*, < unresolved overloaded function type >)'

I asking for all these errors in one question because that all these errors related to this code, and I don't understand why I can't define `operator<<` also for `SquareMatrix` , and in particularly what is give me error while I try to access to the fields that defined at `Matrix` from `operator<<` of SquareMatrix, I don't understand it because that `operator<<` of `SquareMatrix` is defined as a `friend`, hence, it's need to be with access to the fields of object from type of `SquareMatrix` - So what is the reason of this error?

In addition, what is say `unresolved overloaded function type` ? How can I fix it in this case?

Comment: Being private members is true, because they are declared before `public:`.

Comment: @BoPersson But why it's defined as error while I try to access them from `operator<<` of SquareMatrix?

Comment: You are doing the operator in an unusual way - I haven't come to that yet - but suspect it is a friend of `Matrix<T>` but not of `Matrix<S>`.

Comment: The last one is easier - `Plus` is not a type (but a template) so cannot be a parameter. You need the action to be  `Plus<T>`.

Comment: @BoPersson Oh , you right. Thank you about the error with `Plus`. But, about `operator<<` it's not working also if you will try `Matrix<T>` .

Comment: @BoPersson Do you have any idea what the reason for the error with `SquareMatrix::operator<<` ?

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect it is the friend part again - a friend of a derived class is not automatically a friend of the base class. On the other hand, if you already have an operator for the base class, that would work for the derived class as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176008/discussion-between-software-t-and-bo-persson).

Comment: @BoPersson It's not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every instantiation of `Matrix<U>` stamps out a new definition of `template<class S> ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix<S>& m)` - that's why you get redefinition errors.

The correct dance is this - declare `Matrix` template, declare `operator<<`, then define `Matrix` and declare `operator<<` as friend there, and finally, define `operator<<`. Like this:

```
template<class T> class Matrix;

template<class S>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix<S>& m);

template<class T>
class Matrix {
  // ...
  template<class S>
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix<S>& m);
};

template<class S>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix<S>& m) {
  // ...
  return os;
}
```

It's often easier to define a regular public method, say `void print(ostream& os)` that does the actual work, then implement `operator<<` as simply calling that. This way, you don't need to muck around befriending templates, which is somewhat tricky to get right.

Comment: Can you explain please why in the case that I did it inside the class (the `operator<<`) it's not working?

Comment: When you define a friend function within a class definition for the first time (without prior declaration), it's as if it's defined at the enclosing namespace scope, right after the closing brace of the class. When you do the same in a class template definition, every instantiation of the template generates a new definition of the friend. This works when that friend actually mentions the befriending class' template parameters in its signature - then instantiations stamp out different function overloads. But in your case, the friend doesn't use `T`, so all definitions end up identical.